# List of a List unhandled exception C#

Tags: c#, list

Can someone explain me why if I use the Clear() method after the temp var is already stored in ResList. I get the unhandled exception.

I try to use a "temp" list to fill a result list, but after I use the Clear method to reuse the "temp" list and then I try to get one of the previously stored list on the result list I got the "unhandled error"

This is the code to explain they problem:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<int> temp = new List<int>();
        IList<IList<int>> resList = new List<IList<int>>();

        temp.Add(0);
        temp.Add(1);

        resList.Add(temp);

        temp.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("testVar[1][1]{0}", resList[0][1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you've cleared the list, the same list that is also referenced as an entry in `resList`? Your question would be better if you included the exception text, though I expect it's `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: If you clear a list, how do you then expect to get the second item in that list?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you don't understand how objects and references work. When you do this:

```cs
resList.Add(temp);
```

you are not somehow copying the items from `temp` into `resList`. You are actually adding a reference to `temp` itself into `resList`. `resList[0]` and `temp` now refer to the same object, so any changes you make via one reference will be reflected in the other. It's just like if your sister puts a red hat on, it should not be a surprise to your mother that her daughter is wearing a red hat. It's just two ways to refer to the same thing. You can see that for yourself because `resList[0] == temp` is `true`. That means that `temp.Clear()` and `resList[0].Clear()` are effectively doing exactly the same thing, so you should not then be able to get an item from that list via either reference.